# Lowest and highest product prices from combinations (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop

I made Product object override with lowest_price and highest_price fields and I want to get these prices according to product combinations and specificPrice included.

I tried to get them with Product::getPriceStatic method with some hooks (like actionObjectProductUpdateAfter, actionProductUpdate, actionAdminProductControllerSaveAfter), but it seems like prices in that method updates after all these hooks and when I change product combination price through admin controller I didn't get the price changes.

So my question is which way would be the best to get these price calculations when updating product?

*I find a way with Tools::getValues and actionAdminProductControllerSaveAfter hook to get all prices from combinations, then with foreach of them add base product price and that's how I get lowest and highest price, but then I need to check for specificPrice rules and make some more calculations, so Product::getPriceStatic method looked much more simplier.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.